# How to get the content type from a ServletResponse?

Tags: java

I'm implementing a filter, which overrides the `doFilter` method, to insert in the response header some "cache-control" values. The thing is that I only want that values to be set in the responses with a JSON content type. I tried to call `response.getContentType` before set the new header values but it always evaluates to null.

```
 @Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {

        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        if(response != null) {

            final HttpServletResponseWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response);

            if(wrapper.containsHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
                    && wrapper.getHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE).equals("application/json")) {

                response.setHeader("Expires", "Mon, 23 Aug 1982 12:00:00 GMT");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
            }
        }

    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    catch(final Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `get` if you want to set content type? In any case, just read documentation, it explains all. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getContentType--

Comment: You'll have to show us your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: *When* do you attempt to get the content type?

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty with servlet filters is that they are too coarse-grained for that kind of functionality. The `doFilter` method is "all-or-nothing", that is there is nothing set in the response *before* it is called and the entire response is already committed *after* it returns so it's too late then to add any header.

What you can do instead is to wrap the response and intercept the `setHeader` method in the wrapper, then pass that to `doFilter`. There is a helper class [HttpServletResponseWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) designed for that purpose.